# Why is 'badbit' not being set in the case of 'input1' and `input1_5`?

Tags: c++

In this context, please assume it has already been verified that you have a string consisting of `0123456789-.` . This is for the purpose of further validation that the string is actually a stream of `double` values.

I have one question about the example that I have written below purely in order to illustrate my questions:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void dealWithInput(const string&)
int main(){
    
    string input0 = "1 2 3";    // Failed, EOF, correct values (adheres to expectations)
    
    string input1 = "1 2 3-";   // Failed, EOF, 'test' set to 0 due to failure to convert and printed outside of loop on fourth iteration, badbit not set (does not adhere to expectations)

    string input1_5 = "1 2 3--";   // Failed, buffer position 5, 'test' set to 0 due to failure to convert and printed outside of loop on fourth iteration, badbit not set (does not adhere to expectations)
    
    string input2 = "1 2-3";    // Failed, EOF, correct values (does not adhere to expectations)
    string input3 = "1 2 -3 "; // Failed, EOF, correct values (adheres to expectations)
    string input4 = ".1 2---3  ";   // Failed, buffer position 4, 'test' set to 0   (adheres to expectations)
    string input5 = ".1        2       3     "; // Failed, EOF, correct values      (adheres to expectations)
    string input6 = ".1 2 --3 ";    // Failed, buffer position 4, 'test' set to (adheres to expectations)
    string input7 = ".1 - 2 3";     // Failed, buffer position 2, 'test set to 0 (does not adhere to expecctations)

    dealWithInput(input1);
    
}

void dealWithInput(const string& input){
    istringstream buffer(input);
    double test = 0;
    while (buffer >> test){
        cout << "In loop" << endl;
        cout << "Value of test: " << test << endl;
        cout << "Buffer position: " << buffer.tellg() << endl;
    }
    cout << "Out of loop" << endl;
    cout << test << endl;
    
    if (buffer.good())          // no error flags set
        cout << "Good" << endl;
    if (buffer.bad())           // read/write error on i/o (integrity of stream lost) -> never set?
        cout << "Bad" << endl;
    if (buffer.fail())          // logical error on i/o (failure to convert) -> set on EOF
        cout << "Failed" << endl;
    if (buffer.eof())           // EOF reached on input op
        cout << "EOF" << endl;
}
```

Why is `bad()` not set for `input1` or `input1_5`? I would expect it to be for the trailing `-`, upon the conversion error. It should be noted that the same behavior is exhibited if there is more than one trailing `.`, where there is a conversion error, and `badbit` is not set.

Say, for example, you wanted to directly use `while(buffer >> array[j])`. You could not, instead, you'd have to use the wrapper `while(buffer >> some_double) { // only add to your array if it enters the loop }`. This is the problem this creates.

Comment: rather than modifying the code for each case this code could benefit a lot from a function

Comment: You are correct @463035818_is_not_a_number . I'll edit the post. Where do I put the output results for each case then? Again, this is just for example, but I do think the function will make it more clear to the reader.

Comment: The role of white spaces in input is to separate *entities*, such as words in this sentence.  Usually, multiple white spaces can be treated as one white space.

Comment: 1) `"1 2 3-"` is perfectly good input for three numbers, the `-` stops the read of the third number but does not cause any kind of error

Comment: why do you expect the bad bit to be set for `intput1` ?

Comment: So it functions much the same way as `cin` @ThomasMatthews ?

Comment: `cin` is an `istream`

Comment: @user18348324 All kinds of streams follow the same rules, that's part of the design.

Comment: @John For the case of `1 2 3-`, wouldn't it need to detect another digit for the `-` to be valid? That is why I'm wondering. For example, imagine I'm doing `buffer >> array[I]`, I wouldn't want it to affect my array.

Comment: the question is unclear, because 1) why should it be set? 2) what do you mean exactly? Did you get output different from what you expected?

Comment: I would expect `badbit` to be set because the final `-` is not a valid input and should result in read/write error @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: @user18348324 Yes you are right, for some reason I thought your code only tried to read three numbers. When you try to read the fourth number from that input you will get an error.

Comment: " wouldn't it need to detect another digit for the - to be valid?" what do you mean with "valid" ? You try to extract `double`s from the stream, there is a `1` a `2` and a `3` and then something that isnt a number, hence extraction fails after extracting 3 numbers

Comment: Exactly, and there is a conversion error. Therefore, `badbit` should be set @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: ok, cool, now add that to the question, so it is more readable and not hidden in comments :)

Comment: Just did @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: @John That is exactly why I expect `badbit` to be set, since it's affecting input and is not purely warranting of only `failbit` being set.

Comment: but isnt just `while( buffer >> test) my_array[++i] = test;` sufficient to read the numbers?

Comment: It is @463035818_is_not_a_number , but check my updated question.

Comment: @user18348324 `failbit`is correct because you failed to convert `-` into a number. `badbit` is for stream errors (e.g. losing a socket connection, or your hard disk filling up) not for format errors.

Comment: Thank you @John . The question is answered. The consequence of this is you couldn't do `while(buffer >> array[j++]);`

Comment: @user18348324 I'm not sure I understand the consequence, your code looks like a reasonable way to read items into an array.

Comment: not sure but i think your are trying to get something similar to `while( !buffer.eof()) { ...read from buffer..}`, which is wrong, because you only know that you are at eof after you read. Same with extracting a `double`, you need to try to extract one, before you can know that one can be extracted.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I was considering `while(!(buffer.peek() == EOF))`, but I want to allow the user to have whitespaces after the final valid input, but only whitespaces.

Comment: @John the main thing is that I get to be a little less draconian about my input. I wanted to force the user to format it using only input like `-1 0.1 2.3 .5` where every double is in human readable format, and whitespaces are ignored. Perhaps that would require writing a simple program that iterates through and checks for that, though it seems excessive.

Comment: [what is the xy problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Its not clear why you consider `while(buffer >> some_double)` a "problem" or what you actually are trying to solve.

Comment: you can extract doubles and when done check if there is anything left in the stream. If there is, the input was not valid.

Comment: How can I do that @463035818_is_not_a_number ? What function? This would resolve the issue of stuff being at the end, but not if the user were to do `2 - 3 5`.

Comment: function? Its just what you have already. `while (buffer >> test){`. And for checking if there is something left I would simply extract a string and check its size

Comment: btw please do not add answers to the question. Comments arent answers anyhow. Answers should go below to the answer section. If you like you can even answer your own question, but please do not do that in the question, because the question is for the question

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Ok. I'll remove it. But see, now you're getting to why I wanted `badbit` in the first place, it's to check to see if there was something like that left after the valid inputs, which `EOF` can't do for me. Extracting a string and checking the size wouldn't work since a double can be `2023.46` or `3`.

Comment: you extract doubles until no more double can be extracted via `while( buffer >> a_double)` and only after that you extract a string. That string is either empty, then there have been only doubles in the stream, or not

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I think the actual question you wanted to ask is "How to check if a stream contains only doubles?", but I'm not sure

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I was asking 'why isn't badbit able to check whether the stream contains only doubles?' but yes. Thank you for the partial solution. I'm still not sure how to do `34 - 5 .6` or something where it's not totally human-readable, but the stream recognizes it as a double. I think that would have to be my own function.

Comment: Although, the string would still not be empty in the case of `input1` since EOF was reached upon the failure to convert.

Answer (score 0):

The question was answered by @John in the comments. Badbit is for stream errors like losing a socket connection or your hard drive filling up. Perhaps `error on read/write on I/o` is a bit misleading @cppreference